# onSessionStateChange does whatever it wants

Tags: java, android, facebook

I know the title may be odd, but since I've changed my app's lifecycle by moving the login cycle from the `MainActivity` to the `LoginActivity`, Facebook's `onSessionStateChange` does ABSOLUTELY NOTHING of what i ask him.

The login's lifecycle, using Facebook, logs the user to Facebook, gets his UID from fb, and retrieve his infos from our app's server using his UID, and then starts the next activity. But now that I've changed the app's lifecycle, it starts the next activity without even getting the UID.

So here is the code for the `onSessionStateChange` in the `LoginActivity` :

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState sessionState, Exception exception){
    //Make change only if the activity is visible
    if(isResumed){
        Log.i("facebook", "FB state changed");
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        //clear the back stack
        for(int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++){
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }

        if(sessionState.isOpened()){
            Log.i("facebook", "FB session opened");
            //if the facebook session is opened, display the default behavior and add the uid
            //to shared preferences

            //Now let's update shared preferences with uid.
            final Session requestSession = session;
            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response){
                    if(requestSession == Session.getActiveSession() && user != null){
                        Log.i("facebook", "Request UID " + user.getId());
                        GetUserByUIDTask userTask = new GetUserByUIDTask(getParent());
                        userTask.execute(new User(user.getId()));

                        //Get and update the current user from the database
                        try{
                            MainActivity.sCurrentUser = userTask.get();
                            Log.i("facebook", MainActivity.sCurrentUser.firstName
                                    + "'s UID is " + MainActivity.sCurrentUser.uid);
                            updateCurrentUserSettings();

                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            //TODO: Handle and display error
                            Log.e("facebook", "error getting user from uid");
                            return;
                        }catch (ExecutionException e){
                            //TODO: Handle and display error
                            Log.e("facebook", "error getting user from uid");
                            return;
                        }

                        Log.d("facebook", "Displaying Main Activity");
                        //startActivity(new Intent(getParent(), MainActivity.class));
                    }else{
                        Log.e("facebook", "Error when making newMeRequest");
                    }
                }
            });

            request.executeAsync();
        }else if(sessionState.isClosed()){
            Log.i("myapp", "closing session");

            //Remove the current uid to prevent unauthorized authentication and GCM bind
            getSharedPreferences(userPrefsFile,0).edit().clear().commit();;
            try {
                GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this).unregister();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //TODO: handle
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i should get a lot of `Log` output, telling me that the session is being opened, and the `MainActivity` should not be started (since i commented it for testing purposes). But i actually get **absolutely** no log output, and the `MainActivity` still gets launched, even though I've commented it. And when the activity is started, the current user is not updated or even created, leading to a classic crash.

Also you may need the other `LoginActivity`'s facebook related methods :

```
private boolean isResumed = false;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback sessionStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback(){
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception){
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //bind the fb session callback listener to the ui helper and call its lifecycle method
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, sessionStatusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    RegisterChoicesFragment registerFragment = new RegisterChoicesFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.login_container,
            registerFragment).commit();
}//end onCreate



@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    isResumed = true;
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments(){
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(session != null && session.isOpened()){
        //If the current facebook session exists and is opened, make sure that the autheticated
        //UI is selected
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LovRMain.class));
    }
}
```

So here it is, I have absolutely no idea of what makes Facebook API behave like **IT** wants, and I've come to the point where i realize that i hate coding with facebook as much as i hate coding for IE.

Comment: Is what you posted your full activity? Where do you actually open the session?

Comment: I open the session using the facebook's login button contained in the `registerFragment`. `onSessionStateChange` is contained in the activity.
Other methods are related to the classic login with mail/passwd pairs.

Comment: I'm confused as to how many activities/fragments you have, and which one opens the Session. If you open the session in a different fragment or activity, the callback that you register here won't be called.

Comment: The session is opened in a fragment called by the `LoginActivity`, which is a `FragmentActivity`. Once the session is opened in the `LoginActivity`, the `MainActivity` is started, but only when the session is opened and all requests to the app server have been fulfilled, which is not the case since it directly starts the `MainActivity` without making any request to the app's server.

Comment: I see a couple of issues. 1. onActivityResult is called before onResume, and since facebook login results come back via onActivityResult, your isResumed var will be false when the session is transitioning to the OPENED state (which is probably why you're not seeing any logs); remove the isResumed check in your onSessionStateChange. 2. There must be code somewhere else that's calling your MainActivity (since Facebook has no idea what your activities are called, it must be something in your code that's starting the MainActivity).

Comment: Yup, that's it indeed. I was blindly following the documentation, and I put a `startActivity` in the `onResumeFragments`, which worked in the previous configuration but does not work anymore with this configuration.

Problem is solved now, thank to you =)